# Cannot Access Local Drive Using Citrix Receiver Windows 10

Tags: windows, remote-access, citrix, citrix-access-gateway

I am running Windows 10 and just installed the latest Citrix Receiver application.

I am trying to access my local drive to transfer files to and from the remote access to my local drive. However, I am having problems as I do not see a connection to my local drive under the "Network" folder on the remote drive.

Any help is appreciated.